# Is there a way to transfer data between a python import module and the code?

Tags: python, function, module

I was wondering if it is poses to transfer data from a python module back to the code that it uses. Preferably without any extra modules being needed.
Example:
One code has lots of functions inside of it(code A). Each function performs an api task that is given back in a .json form. The second code(code B) imports the first code(A) and runs one of those functions. Is it possible to send that .json stored within a variable back to code B

Comment: You shouldn't generally modify code in place like this. Why not save the JSON in a file?

Comment: @Cameron no I edited it to help clarify